# Nodejs: sharing session across meteor and express app running as separate instances

Tags: node.js, meteor, kue

Basically, the user is logged in on the meteor app running on localhost:30000 using the accounts-ui package. Express app is running on localhost:34444.

At some point, a user will need to use the express app (it's actually Kue), and I want to avoid having users login twice.

Both instances are running on same domain, just different ports.

My end goal is to have a job queue management) accessible by a user logged on from another web server instance (in this case meteor), all in the same domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Redis for that. Fast and easy. If you plan on using Memcached (somehow easier) you might have problems with racing conditions, because memcached have no locking mechanism